# How to prevent/lint the use of Error constructor?

Tags: babeljs, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'd like to be able to prevent the use of `new Error('some message')` so I can recommend that my developers in my repo to use the preferred error, `MacroError`.

How can do that with Eslint?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the open-ended rule called `'no-restricted-syntax'` that lets you use AST information. This is the section you'd want to add to the `rules` object within `.eslintrc.js`:

```json
rules: {
    // ... other rules
    'no-restricted-syntax': [
      'error',
      {
        selector: "NewExpression[callee.name='Error']",
        message: "Use MacroError from 'babel-plugin-macros' instead",
      },
    ],
    'no-console': 'error',
    // ... other rules
},
```